# Error when changing a vector value in a class

Tags: c++, class, variables, vector, double

I am attempting to change a value in a vector which is a variable in a class using a function of a class. When I compile, i get the following errors pointing to the "check[c] = cval;" line:

- error C3867: 'acc::check': function call missing argument list; use '&acc::check' to create a pointer to member
- error C2109: subscript requires array or pointer type

Note: I have already initialized C to be 0 elsewhere in the program. It might be throwing an error because I am giving the address a variable instead of an integer, but when I substitute the variable with an integer, I still get the same errors.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <string>
    #include <vector>
    #include <cstring>

    using namespace std;

    class acc
    {
    public:
        void add_Cval(double cval);

    private:
        vector<double> check(); //vector of all checks
        int c;                  //loop marker for cvals
    };

    void acc::add_Cval(double cval)
    {
        check[c] = cval;
        c++;
    }
```

Comment: Google "the most vexing parse".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`check` is a method, not a data member, so you need to invoke it - `check()`.

```
void acc::add_Cval(double cval)
{
    check()[c] = cval;
    c++;
}
```

or make it a data member:

```
class acc
{
public:
    void add_Cval(double cval);

private:
    vector<double> check; //vector of all checks
    int c;                  //loop marker for cvals
};
```

Comment: actually, now that I saw this one, it is much cleaner and more relevant. Thank you everybody!

Answer (score 6):

`vector<double> check();` isn't what you think it is. You just declared a function named `check` that returns a `vector<double>`. Get rid of the parenthesis like so `vector<double> check;`.

Also, your `vector<double>` is empty, you need to give it some space if you want to do `check[c] = cval;` (or use `check.push_back(cval);` instead), allocate the space in the constructor (use "initialization lists" as that is what they are for):

Example:

```
acc(int vecsize) : check(vecsize), c(0) {}
```

You might also want to make sure `check[c]` is a valid position in the vector before assigning anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is looking for a function called `check()` that returns a vector of type double.

```
private:
    vector<double> check(); // A private function that returns a vector of type <double>
```

Needs to be:

```
private:
    vector<double> check;  // A private data member
```